# Factorization of Gegenbauer polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

For each natural number $n$ there is a Gegenbauer polynomial of degree n, depending on 
a spectral parameter $\lambda$. They fulfill many recurrent relations. The question is
how to recognize their factorization properties (employing recursive relations, say), 
i.e. for which value of the spectral parameter $\lambda$ and $n\geq m$, the degree $n$ Gegenbauer is divisible by degree $m$ Gegenbauer.